# iptables allow only certain services

Tags: iptables

I am running in my server asterisk and I would like to protect my system as much as possible. It is currently protected with fail2ban and I would like to add some more protection. Ideally I would like to block everything and allow only:

- ssh, port 33332
- asterisk, port 35060
- RTP 10000 up to 200000

and

- Block 3 failed ssh attempts in the last 10minutes, for 1day
- block ICMP

Answer (score 1):

I believe these rules will help

```
# Drop everything
iptables -P INPUT DROP

# Allow certain ports
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 33332 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 35060 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 10000:20000 -j ACCEPT

# Disable ICMP
iptables  -I  INPUT  -i  eth0  -p   icmp  -s  0/0  -d  0/0   -j  DROP
```

And ofcourse need to save the rules.Iptables-persistent is nice tool for this:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

After it's installed, you can save/reload iptables rules anytime:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent save 
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent reload
```

SSH blocking is done in /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf or */etc/fail2ban/jail.local*

```
bantime  = 86400
findtime = 600
maxretry = 3
```

Good luck!

Comment: it comes with an error   iptables -A INPUT venet0:0 -p tcp --dport 33332 -j ACCEPT                               
Bad argument `venet0:0'                                                                                      
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.  It is a vps and the ethernet is on venet0:0

Comment: Then you could just replace eth0 with venet0:0

Comment: You can not use an aliased interface name with iptables. You have to use the base interface name, and then further refine, if required, via destination IP address.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for the answers. i have tried the one with the /root/iptables.sh script.
it works. The only question i have, is when i do need to add new rules to that script how do i start stop the iptables to get the new rules, please?

Comment: i am using the solution /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent and it works. if i would like to disable the firewall temporarilly, how do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

Create `iptables.sh` and put in `/root/`

Give x permission

```
chmod +x /root/iptables.sh
```

Edit `/etc/rc.local` to trigger script on reboot

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

add at the end of file

```
 sh /root/iptables.sh
```

Script

```
#!/bin/bash

#echo service iptables stop | at now + 3 min

#################################################
# clear existing chains
#################################################

/etc/init.d/iptables stop

iptables --flush
iptables --delete-chain

#################################################
# allow loopback
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# drop all ICMP
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j DROP

#################################################
# allow established connections
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# allow public
#################################################

# 33332 
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 33332 -j ACCEPT

# 35060
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 35060 -j ACCEPT

# RTP 10000 up to 200000
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --match multiport --dports 10000:20000 -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# ssh
#################################################

iptables -N ATTACKED 
iptables -N ATTK_CHECK 
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --update --seconds 86400 --name BANNED --rsource -j DROP
iptables -A ATTACKED -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 3 -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES (Rule ATTACKED): " --log-level 7
iptables -A ATTACKED -m recent --set --name BANNED --rsource -j DROP
iptables -A ATTK_CHECK -m recent --set --name ATTK –-rsource
iptables -A ATTK_CHECK -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 3 --name ATTK --rsource -j ATTACKED
iptables -A ATTK_CHECK -j ACCEPT


#################################################
# default policies
#################################################

iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Comment: If you want to add new rule in `iptables.sh` simple edit script, add rule and start it again with command `sudo sh /root/iptables.sh`. You don't need to stop iptables before editing action.

Comment: i have tried to open a new port and then issue sh /root/iptables.sh
the problem is that i am getting an error:     root@chip:~# sh /root/iptables.sh
/root/iptables.sh: 9: /root/iptables.sh: /etc/init.d/iptables: not found
root@chip:~#

Comment: also root@chip:~# /etc/init.d/iptables
-bash: /etc/init.d/iptables: No such file or directory
root@chip:~# does not work

Comment: dear 2707974, i have the forementioned script with the sh /root/iptables.sh in /etc/rc.local and it works fine. The only thing that i am looking to find out is how do i stop/reload/start the iptables. at the moment all i am doing is comment/uncomment the line in /etc/rc.local and reboot the system. this is not very productive. is there any other way to stop/reload/start the iptables, please?          also i am getting an error when trying to run by hand

Comment: root@chip: ~ $ sh /root/iptables.sh                                             
Automatic flushing disabled, use "flush" instead of "stop"                      
iptables v1.4.14: multiple -j flags not allowed                                 
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.                    
root@chip: ~ $

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing a firewall builder like `shorewall` or `ufw`.  Only allow incoming traffic on the ports required for the services you want to provide.  These tools will help ensure you allow critical traffic like DNS and certain ICMP types, while blocking things that need to be blocked.  They should also log appropriate traffic.

`fail2ban` does work with Shorewall.  You can also ratelimit connections relatively easily.  I haven't successfully used UFW, but I expect it would also work with `fail2ban.